# Is there a good rule of thumb for plurals of words ending in "o"?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, suffixes, silent-letters, irregular

The following words and their plurals seem to be somewhat inconsistent:

- combo / combos
- concerto / concertos
- grotto / grottos / grottoes (?)
- hero / heros (?) / heroes
- potato / potatos (?) / potatoes
- tornado / tornados / tornadoes
- tomato / tomatos / tomatoes
- volcano / volcanos / volcanoes

Is there a common source for *-s* versus *-es*? With regards to words such as "heros", is it likely to see more words start dropping *-es* in favor of *-s*?

(If you have any other good examples of strange plurals from words ending in "o" feel free to edit them into the question.)

Comment: I don't think you can include "combo" in that list. It's slang for "combination".

Comment: @Al: "Combo" has its own entry in my dictionary along with a rule for pluralizing it. It being slang for "combination" is likely why it gets _-s_ instead of _-es_ which, presumably, would be part of the answer to this question. But "combo" is a word and it is pluralized and it does end in "o". Therefore, I consider it relevant to this question.

Comment: I think Al has it right: `combo` is slang and that's why it's irregular.  All the others are `-oes`.

Comment: @Al, @Mal: If you think that is the answer than post it as an answer. :) Simple but correct answers are still correct. But I am still curious about _potatos_.

Comment: Never seen it spelled "potatos".

Comment: @Al: That's the point. The "combo" bit is only one abnormality; "potatos" is apparently incorrect but most of the other words have "-s" as acceptable variant. I was curious about a possible reason for the differences.

Comment: @MrHen maybe you can post that as a question? I'm curious also about that one! :)

Comment: @page: I did. This _is_ that question.

Comment: @MrHen just thinking that the tomatoes/tomato and potatoes/potato should have its own question (I think it's from a song?)

Comment: @page: There is a song called [Let's Call the Whole Thing Off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Call_the_Whole_Thing_Off) which talks about the different ways to pronunce words but it has nothing to do with spelling or plurals as far as I know. I don't see anything in the potatoes/potato question that isn't dealt with here but if you do feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: @PaulAmerigoPajo - [Now they have their own question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426341/why-tomatoes-and-potatoes-instead-of-tomatos-and-potatos)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/) (p. 1586, *The alternation between ·s and ·es*) has to say about it:

> With bases ending in *o*, where *o* does not follow a consonant symbol (i.e. where it is preceded by a vowel or is part of the composite vowel symbol *oo*), the plural takes ·s:
>
> > *bamboos, cameos, embryos, folios, kangaroos, patios, radios, studios, zoos*
>
> Where *o* does follow a consonant, the plural has to be specified for the lexeme concerned. There are three classses:
>
> > i. ·*es* only: *echo* ~ *echoes*. Also ***domino, embargo, hero, mango, negro, potato, tomato, torpedo, veto***
> >
> > ii. ·*s* or ·*es*: motto ~ mottos/mottoes. Also, ***archipelago, banjo, buffalo, cargo, dado, dodo, grotto, halo, innuendo, manifesto, mulatto, proviso, tornado, volcano***
> >
> > iii. ·*s* only: *bistro* ~ *bistros*. Also ***calypso, do, dynamo, beano;*** clippings such as ***demo, kilo, memo, photo;*** nouns of Italian origin: ***cello, concerto, contralto, libretto, maestro, piano, quarto, solo, soprano, virtuoso;*** and names of ethnic groups: ***Chicano, Eskimo, Filipino, Texano***.
>
> ***Cargo*** and ***volcano*** are marginal members of class [ii]: they usually take ·*es*, but the forms *cargos* and *volcanos* are sometimes found.

As an additional rule of thumb, almost of all the exceptions for the *consonant + o + s = es* rule seem to involve plural nouns where there is no homophonous verb, as per CGEL, p. 1580.

For class [ii], it might be useful to use Google Books Ngram Viewer to assess the ·*s*/·*es* distribution, and to go with the ending that seems to be preferred in literary sources. For instance,

[Google Books Ngram Viewer — *mottos* vs *mottoes* — English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=mottos%2C+mottoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image]
[Google Books Ngram Viewer — *banjos* vs *banjoes* — English](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=banjos%2C+banjoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually I do believe that the rule is:

- *-oes* for most words ending in *-o*: potatoes, tomatoes
- *-os* for any words related (usually) to music (i.e. loanwords, from Italian). These would include: pianos, crescendos, radios, concertos, sopranos, pimentos (loanword), etc.

Comment: It's not strictly a *rule* since you'll find exceptions. It is however a useful guideline that is correct much of the time.

Answer (score 2):

If the noun ends with *vowel + o*, just add *-s*:  *radios*, *zoos*.

If it’s a music word, it’s probably Italian, so just add *-s*:  *pianos*, *concertos*.

Otherwise, look it up in a dictionary. There is no rule of thumb that correctly covers all words. Many nouns ending with *-o* can take either *-es* or *-s* but one or the other is preferred.

(This answer is informed by a recent attempt of mine to boil down *CGEL*’s spelling rules for plurals and suffixes to something my kids could memorize. *CGEL* is the *[Cambridge Grammar of the English Langauge](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/)*. I was not all that successful.)

Answer (score 1):

To complete the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/23260/37429), I found a similar, but more extensive information in [Oxford dictionaries -> Plural of nouns](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/plurals-of-nouns):

> Nouns ending in -o can add either -s or -es in the plural, and some
>   can be spelled either way.
>
> As a general rule, most nouns ending in -o add -s to make the plural:
>
> ```
> singular    plural
> --------------------
> solo        solos
> zero        zeros
> avocado     avocados
> ```
>
> Those which have a vowel before the final -o always just add -s:
>
> ```
> singular    plural
> -------------------
> studio      studios
> zoo         zoos
> embryo      embryos
> ```
>
> Here’s a list of the most common nouns ending in -o that are always
>   spelled with -es in the plural:
>
> ```
> singular    plural
> ----------------------
> buffalo     buffaloes
> domino      dominoes
> echo        echoes
> embargo     embargoes
> hero        heroes
> mosquito    mosquitoes
> potato      potatoes
> tomato      tomatoes
> torpedo     torpedoes
> veto        vetoes
> ```
>
> Here are some of the common nouns ending in -o that can be spelled
>   with either -s or -es in the plural:
>
> ```
> singular    plural
> -----------------------------------
> banjo       banjos    or banjoes
> cargo       cargos    or cargoes
> flamingo    flamingos or flamingoes
> fresco      frescos   or frescoes
> ghetto      ghettos   or ghettoes
> halo        halos     or haloes
> mango       mangos    or mangoes
> memento     mementos  or mementoes
> motto       mottos    or mottoes
> tornado     tornados  or tornadoes
> tuxedo      tuxedos   or tuxedoes
> volcano     volcanos  or volcanoes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess from an observation on your examples:

- two consonants before the *-o* gives *-os*;
- one consonant before the *-o* gives *-oes*;

Although checking the dictionary reveals that both spelling are correct. Could be British/American English thing?