# Is there any difference between "tuxedo" and "avocado" with regard to their plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

An English exam is slowly coming closer and closer, so I'm trying to revise...

I'm holding an English learning book right now, and the very first chapter is dedicated to regular and irregular plural forms of nouns. One exercise wants me to cross out words that are not fitting; for example, from "*cows*", "*tables*", "*bags*", "*news*", the last noun ("*news*") goes away, because it only has plural form; and from "*play*", "*family*", "*dictionary*", "*university*", "*play*" goes away, because its plural is "*plays*" and not "*plaies*".

So now I'm stuck with "*potato*", "*avocado*", "*tomato*", "*tuxedo*". As far as I'm aware, the plural forms of these nouns are: "*potatoes*", "*avocados*", "*tomatoes*", "*tuxedos*". So we can say there are two groups with two words per each group: "*potatoes*" and "*tomatoes*" vs "*avocados*" and "*tuxedos*". Yet the book authors want me to cross "*tuxedo*" out. How is "*tuxedo*" any different than "*avocado*"? To me, these two words are exactly the same, since, in both cases, the plural form is constructed by adding "*-s*" and not "*-es*".

What am I failing to grasp?

Edit: As per the request from the comments:

> **tux•e•do**
>
> **n.[countable], pl.  -dos.**

[from WordReference.com definition of tuxedo](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/tuxedo)

> **av•o•ca•do**
>
> **n.[countable], pl.  -dos.**

[from WordReference.com definition of avocado](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/avocado)

> **to•ma•to**
>
> **n.[countable], pl.  -toes.**

[from WordReference.com definition of tomato](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/tomato)

> **po•ta•to**
>
> **n., pl.  -toes.**

[from WordReference.com definition of potato](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/potato)

Comment: Good question. To make it clear that you have already tried to figure this out on your own before asking here, I would advise editing in some dictionary definitions that corroborate what you say. The only difference I can think of between _tuxedo_ and the other three is that the other three have an a in the paenult; but that doesn’t affect its plural form, so that seems like it would be an odd answer.

Comment: This exercise doesn't sound like it was designed very well. The words "play", "family", "dictionary", "university" can all be considered to have regular plural forms: [the change of terminal "-y" to "-ies" is not regular when the "y" forms part of a vowel digraph](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/when-should-a-singular-word-ending-in-y-end-in-ies-plurally). It's clear that "play" is different from the other words, but the idea of "not fitting" is a pretty vague concept that doesn't seem like it would be very useful for learning about regular vs. irregular plural forms.

Comment: Related: [Is there a good rule of thumb for plurals of words ending in “o”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23229)

Comment: Yes, there is a good rule, but it doesn't have to do with spelling. Nouns ending in /o/ like _zero, potato, tuxedo_ add a /-z/ suffix to form plural. This always works. But since English spelling is arbitrary and not rule-governed, this doesn't tell you how to spell those plurals. However, nobody cares how you spell them, since everybody has trouble with this, and you get understood either way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is it OK now?

Comment: Yes, perfect! @JohnLawler Exams, which is what gaazkam is studying for, do care. And whether we like them or not, exams do have actual impact on people’s lives.

Comment: What's the title of this book, please? And be careful, sometimes test questions will ask for "two" wrong answers, so I just want to be sure the wording is unambiguous. But nice question, food for thought, ho ho, ho....  what would be the plural form of "ho" I ask myself 

Comment: Obviously, *tuxedo* is the odd one out because you can't eat tuxedos. :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA , double checked, they want one word. But, but, I've already seen "dumb" mistakes in this book, I mean mistakes clearly made of carelessness, I'm starting to suppose that's another example of these.

Comment: If the focus is on something as useless as spelling, it's probly just another stupid grammar book written by someone who didn't know any better.

Comment: @PeterShor Have you tried? I’m sure you could if you put your mind to it. ;-)

Comment: My suggestion is to try two or three good dictionaries and see if you can spot any difference, say Oxford, American Heritage, and either Cambridge or Merriam Webster (unfortunately, this last one has an online version with hideous formatting and ads)... you can access them all easily using [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/). Stay away from dictionaries not compiled by professional lexicographers; these include anything with the word 'wiki' in it. Then *after* you have checked two or three reputable dictionaries, ask here. (Word Reference is decent when it's based on Collins, so that is one.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (you speak Polish, don't you? :)   Found a pdf file with the same examples (page 8) but as I don't speak Polish, I don't know what the precise instructions are http://images.nexto.pl/upload/publisher/Langenscheidt/public/jezyk%20angielski%20korepetycje%20domowe%20demo.pdf  But it looks like the editor/author messed up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m afraid I haven’t really tackled Polish yet beyond random tidbits!

Comment: Is it perhaps the book is asking which word is the [*odd one out*](http://www.wordreference.com/enpl/odd%20one%20out)? In which case, @PeterShor got the answer!

Comment: To add to the info from dictionaries, Google Ngrams shows that *avocados* is overwhelmingly more prevalent in what people actually write: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avocados%2Favocadoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28avocados%20/%20avocadoes%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @PeterShort But the tuxedo is the only thing you can find a tailor fitting . . .

Answer (score 1):

Textbooks frequently contain intentional or unintentional misdirection.  In this exercise it wants you to cross out words that are not fitting and the first two examples have words that do not fit due to their regular and irregular plural forms, which the chapter is dedicated to.

The question only implies that the words need not fit due to regular and irregular plural forms by virtue of the question is in that chapter.

The third example, "cross out words that are not fitting", offers the words "potato", "avocado", "tomato", "tuxedo".  There is no requirement that the word to be crossed out is due to their regular and irregular plural forms, it could be that the word "tuxedo" does not fit as ""potato", "avocado", and "tomato" are edible but "tuxedo" is not.

Comment: He said the "chapter is dedicated to regular and irregular plural forms of nouns." Are you suggesting that they threw a trick question into the exercises, and it's not really related the topic of the chapter?

Comment: Learning English spelling is already for masochists, would they really add this additional layer of sadism?

Comment: But, in reverse, the tuxedo is the *only* item that you will find a tailor fitting . . . ;)