# What is the plural of the noun "go" (as in “have a go”)?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, orthography

If I were to try to achieve something you could say I "had a go".

If I tried it multiple times, how would I write that down?

> I had many goes

or

> I had many go's

or

> I had many gos

Comment: Related: [Is there a good rule of thumb for plurals of words ending in “o”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23229/is-there-a-good-rule-of-thumb-for-plurals-of-words-ending-in-o)

Comment: @BillJ et al.: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The dictionaries I've checked seem to be unanimous that the plural of the noun "go" is "goes". I didn't see one list its plural as "gos". However, I didn't check all dictionaries.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/go):
n. pl. goes

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/go):
n, pl goes

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go):
plural goes

[Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go)
plural goes

[Random House Unabridged Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/go) (dictionary.com):
plural goes

[Google NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+gos+at%2Ctwo+goes+at%2Cthree+gos+at%2Cthree+goes+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20goes%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20goes%20at%3B%2Cc0) does not show any results for "two gos at" or "two gos at", but does when written as "goes".

A Google search shows the following results:

"two gos at" = 453 results.
"two goes at" = 19,500 results.
"three gos at" = 252 results.
"three goes at" = 20,200 results.

Note that both Google search and Ngram Viewer may show false positives, as Google search, as far as I know, doesn't take punctuation into account when giving search results, ie., full stops, commas. But I think it's safe to assume the consensus is that the plural of go (attempt or try) is "goes".

I think this is a good question, as somewhere in my head I have an instinct to write it "gos". However the answer is gotten easily by checking some dictionaries.

Also, if you wrote "I had three gos at it before giving up", I have a feeling the typical reader probably wouldn't even be surprised by it or notice it particularly as wrong. This is just my opinion. I have this feeling because the "-os"/"-oes" plural ending rules are wildly inconsistent. Potatoes, tomatoes and heroes are correct. But "photos" and "burritos" are correct. However most dictionaries seem to list either "-os" or "-oes" ending as acceptable in "ghetto" and "mosquito".

Both "mosquito" and "burrito" most likely come from Spanish, yet most dictionaries say only "mosquito" can have plural ending either "-os" or "oes", whereas they're consistent in listing "-os" for burrito plural. Same goes for "canto", "manifesto" and "grotto". These words most likely come from Italian, yet the plural of "canto" is "cantos", whereas the dictionaries say the plural of "grotto" or "manifesto" can end in either "-os" or "-oes".

**Addendum**

As some people have claimed that the rules for -os or -oes plural endings are quite consistent (and I happen to disagree), I've included more examples to show just how unpredictable this can get. The claim generally is basically that borrowed words or imported words from other languages have -os as their endings and most everything else has -oes. The more specific claim is this rule applies for words from Romance languages specifically.

- **embargo (Spanish):** Dictionaries show only -oes plural. NGrams show -oes much more common.
- **tornado (Spanish):** Dictionaries show either -os or -oes plural. NGrams shows -oes much more common.
- **desperado (Spanish):** Dictionaries show either -os or -oes plural. NGrams shows -oes more common.
- **cargo (Spanish) plural possibly as the pants:** Dictionaries show either -os or -oes. NGrams shows -oes more common.
- **mango (Portuguese):** Dictionaries show both -os or -oes. NGrams shows -oes much more common.
- **domino (uncertain exactly which language, but a Romance one, or maybe directly from Latin):** Dictionaries give either -os or -oes.
  NGrams shows -oes much more common.
- **volcano (Italian)**: Dictionaries give either -os or -oes. NGrams shows -oes much more common.
- **motto (Italian):** Dictionaries give either -os or -oes. NGrams shows -oes to be more common.

Words taken directly from Latin many times have -oes plural ending, but not always:

veto has plural vetoes
torpedo has plural torpedoes

However memento overwhelmingly has plural mementos.
And embryo is always embryos.

Echo, directly from Greek, has plural "echoes".

- **hello (native English):** Nearly always "hellos".
- **no (native English):** Much more common as "nos", ie., "yeses and nos".
- **do (native English):** Dictionaries give plural as either "dos" or
  "do's". The results for searches of these terms would be confounding to say the least.
- **weirdo (native English):** some dictionaries show both -os or -oes. NGrams shows -os is much more popular

***Unknown origin:***

- **hobo**: Dictionaries give either -os or -oes. NGrams show roughly same frequency.
- **gizmo**: = Dictionaries only give -os, "gizmoes" doesn't show anything in NGrams.
- **gazebo:** Dictionaries show both -os or -oes. NGrams shows -os more common.

So I don't know about anyone else, but I personally need help, in many ways.

Comment: You can find 'goes' in the  WordWeb Dictionary" https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=go

Comment: "I have a feeling the typical reader probably wouldn't even be surprised by it or notice it particularly as wrong." This typical British reader would. "Gos" looks like it's a singular noun pronounced "Goss" to rhyme with "boss" or "moss" (with a British English "o" sound, not the American English vowel which is closer to a long "a" than a BrE "o").

Comment: @alephzero Yes, you're right, I hope the way I phrased it didn't come off as being a certain claim, it was just my feeling of the "typical" person. I probably exclude people who use this site as typical readers, like you. Sorry if this wasn't clear. We also have the case the of "yeses and nos/noes", where many dictionaries recognise the plural of "no" as either "nos" or "noes". The "nos" spelling I imagine would look like what you have pointed out, ie., "noss".

Comment: If I read "I had three gos on Bob's bike" I would never guess that it referred to "a go".  Apart from the borrowed words which have brought their native plurals along with them, nouns that end in "o" take "es" to form the plural, so it's "goes" for sure.

Comment: The "-os"/"-oes" endings aren't all that inconsistent. The default is to include the *e*, but words imported from Romance languages use "-os". The increasing use of "mosquitoes" is a study in the normalization of an imported Spanish word.

Comment: @CCTO It isn't as simple as that borrowed words have their plural forms borrowed as well, while all other 'o' ending words have a "-oes" ending. I thought I already showed this with multiple examples. "Embargo" is another example of a borrowed word from Spanish, yet only "-oes" is accepted by most dictionaries as the plural form. NGrams and Google search shows that "yeses and nos" is more common than "yeses and noes". And "no" is not a borrowed word as far as I know.

Answer (score 10):

There is an alternate construction which expresses plurality using a singular inflection, which may be of interest. Tho slightly odd, it has a history of use, and is readily understood:

> "many a go"

As in:

> We've had many a go at this.
>
> I'll have many a go.

Comment: Technically, verbs are conjugated, nouns are inflected.

Comment: What do you mean by verbs are conjugated, nouns are inflected? Isn't inflection is the headword which means the process by which words are changed in form to create new, specific meanings? Inflection has two main categories: conjugation and declension. Conjugation refers to the inflection of verbs, while declension refers to the inflection of nouns, pronouns, adjectives, and adverbs.

Comment: @FlonneLightberry word.

Comment: Hah, declension in English :) Not that it doesn't exist but it's very limited.

Comment: Thank you Acccumulation and Flonne, I appreciate learning that distinction.

Answer (score -2):

In most usage I have heard, I would consider the phrase "a go at it" to be non-count. In other words, it does not specify the number of tries and thus neither singular nor plural.

Though, [VizJS](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/471945/288348) answer does seem to be a logical plural.

Comment: A "go" is singular and specifies a single attempt. I can't see how it's non-count if I can have "several goes" - which I should note is a common if informal expression in my experience (Aust. Eng.).

Comment: @Chappo -- I have Western US background. So likely a dialect difference. In my experience, trying to do something doesn't necessarily mean a single attempt.

Comment: It may not be down to regional variation. Dictionary definitions make it pretty clear that a "go" means "**an** attempt", i.e. singular. They're semantically equivalent, and "attempt" is countable. A single "attempt" (or "go" or "try") can include exploring multiple solutions, and could even span a long period, but would usually exclude doing the same thing again - that would be having a "second go" at it.

Answer (score -3):

Not what the OP intended...

The noun *go* (a Japanese board game) has the English plural *gos*.  Perhaps one could even say "I had a go" with this meaning.

Comment: No, you can't say 'gos' for Go which means a Japanese board game. It's a mass noun (uncountable): https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go (example: ‘The game that does seem to me to be superior to chess, in that it has both depth and simplicity, is the Japanese game of Go.’)

Comment: So the plural of `chess` is `chesses`, right? "I had a chess"? I don't think so...

Comment: I had a chess set. I played many chess games. I had a go set. I played many go games. I had many goes at go. I had many goes at chess.

Comment: I've never had a chess at go though, in my entire checkered past.

Comment: @MontyHarder Get a Clue, you don't have a Monopoly on Go.

Comment: @FlonneLightberry As with many, if not most, other mass nouns, _go_ can indeed be pluralised. Such a pluralisation entails type-shifting, and the plural form refers to different _types_ of go. It’s the same principle as when talking about different peoples, monies, or waters, except those are common, whereas many other count nouns are uncommonly enough pluralised that they sound strange when you first encounter them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree - uncommon, sounds weird but is perfectly acceptable. "Jovian chess uses different rules: the two chesses should not be confused".

Comment: So it's acceptable? lol so many exceptions of English language. Ok then, how about that: People in itself is already plural? - (plural) any group of human beings (men, women or children) collectively. If you add s, wouldn't it become superfluous? Even if you want to mean 'many type of people' as in fish/fishes (plural form)?

Comment: How do you determine your decision of  'sounds weird' but acceptable?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To show that yours is the right answer, consider adding explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @FlonneLightberry _People_ is not plural, no. It is morphologically singular. Its most common use is as a non-count noun which takes plural verb agreement, but the noun itself is singular in form. It can also be used as a count noun (“The Zhuang are _a people_ of southern China”), in which case it has a regular plural (“The _peoples_ of southern China include the Zhuang and the Yi”). _Fish(es)_ is quite different: it’s just a count noun that happens to have two different plural form, like _brother_ -> _brothers_ or _brethren_.

Comment: @FlonneLightberry Anything can sound weird if you haven’t heard it before. But if it obeys the underlying rules of grammar, derivation, morphology, phonotactics, etc., then _a priori_ it should be assumed to be valid. Turning non-count nouns into count nouns to refer to individual or multiple distinct types of that noun (or servings, if it’s something ingestible) is a regular, productive process in English; even though it’s only really common with a few specific nouns, that doesn’t make it unacceptable with the other nouns.